# how I can get unselected an option in a select multiple when I click in another option of that same select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm doing a form in html using Materializecss framework, and I have varios selects multiples in my form. I would like to get the next result in my selects:

First, the Option "None" is checked because that option has the attribute "Selected". I want that when I select options like Yellow, Blue or red, the option "None" automatically getting "unckecked". 
Example in this image:

[None has to be unckecked when I select another option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfm37.png)

and If I click on "None" again, the other options have to get unchecked. I want to get that with JQuery but I have tried doing a lot of things but I can't obtain the results that I wish. 
Could you guys Help me? I´m working in a project and this part is really important.

I have tried with functions like prop() and Attr(), removing the attribute "Selected", but it doesn't work. The problem is that Materialize using a plugin to the selects.

This is my code:

```js
var none = true;

function displayValores() {
  var selectValues = $("#myid").val() || [];
  var valueSelect1 = $("#and_or").val();

 
  if (none && (selectValues.length > 1 || selectValues[0] != "None")) {
    
    $("#myid [option=selected]").removeAttr("selected");
   
    selectValues = $("#myid").val()
    
    none = false;
  
  } else if (!none && selectValues.indexOf("None") > -1) {
    
    $("#myid").val("None");
    
    selectValues = $("#myid").val()
    
    none = true;
  }

  $('.show').html(selectValues.join(" " + valueSelect1 + " "));
}

$("select").change(displayValores);
displayValores();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <title>SELECT MATERIALIZE</title>
</head>

<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').select();
  });
</script>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col s4">
  <span>The colours are: </span><span class="show"></span>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s2" style="margin-left: 600px;">
     <select id="and_or">
       <option>and</option>
       <option>or</option>
     </select>
     </div>
   </div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col s4">
  <select id="myid" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="None" selected>None</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
</select>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is possible in jQuery I would advise you to do it differently. Put the 'None' checkbox out of your multiselect checkbox, just in the top of it, and rename it in Select/Unselect all, so when someone check / uncheck it you will have all / none of your input checked.

You can check un input in jQuery in the following way:

```
$('input[value="myValue"]').prop('checked', true);
```

For the select

```
$('option[value="myValue"]').prop('selected', true);
```

**EDIT**

I don't know how your plugin works, but I think that it has some api function to select/unselect option by their value in js. Look at the documentation plugin

Comment: The problem is that I must have the "None" option inside the multiselect. Materializecss use <ul> and <li> elementos inside the select, That framework has a plugin that make it. If I use the function prop() to change the property "selected" in an option, doesn't work perfectly because the checkbox beside to the each option doesn't unchecked. I think the problem is the elements <li>. I want to access to the class "selected active" of each <li> element but I don't know How.